# Set different initial value for a variable with different sub index at pyomo

Tags: python, variables, initialization, pyomo

I get the following basic setting:

```
model.X = ['A','B']
model.stage = range(1,3)
model.Y = ['C','D']
model.area = pyo.Var(model.X, model.stage, model.Y, initialize = 2, bounds=(0,100))
```

but I wish the variable area can be initialized with different value, like

```
model.area['A',1,'C'] initialize = 1
model.area['A',1,'D'] initialize = 1
model.area['B',1,'C'] initialize = 2
model.area['B',1,'D'] initialize = 2
model.area['A',2,'C'] initialize = 1
model.area['A',2,'D'] initialize = 1
model.area['B',2,'C'] initialize = 2
model.area['B',2,'D'] initialize = 2
```

I get no idea how to iterate the defined variable area with different sub index, can anyone share some ideas ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the `model` object is a `ConcreteModel` you can simply write

```
model.area['A',1,'C'].value = 1
model.area['B',1,'C'].value = 2
```

If it is an `AbstractModel` you can either do the same on the constructed instance or you can define a rule and assign it to the initialize keyword:

```
def area_init(m,i,j,k):
    if (i,j,k) in [('A',1,'C'),...]:
        return 1
    elif ...:
        return 2
model.area = pyo.Var(model.X,model.stage,model.Y,initialize=area_init,bounds=(0,100))
```

Comment: Yeah, it is ConcreteModel, and it founctions well when I put them directly after the declare of model.area.